# Quadratic equation with roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: quadratics

if $\alpha$, $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, then the roots of the equation $a(2x+1)^2 + b(2x + 1) + c = 0$ are -

Comment: I believe that $a\neq0$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far? Seeing what work you've done will help others provide you with better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $y=2x+1$, solve for $y$ then solve for $x$.